# Convert JS function magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to convert this function in magento2 phtml file

```
<select id="myURLs" onclick="openPop();">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Select Size Guide</option>
<option value="size-guide-kids/">Kids</option>
<option value="size-guide-adults/">Adults</option>
</select>


<script>
function openPop(){
  var Sel_Ind = document.getElementById('myURLs').selectedIndex;
  var popUrl = document.getElementById('myURLs').options[Sel_Ind].value;
  console.log(popUrl);
  if(popUrl!=""){
  winpops=window.open(popUrl,"","width=1000,height=700,resizable,");
   console.log(winpops);
 }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add on your phtml:

```
<select id="myURLs">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Select Size Guide</option>
    <option value="size-guide-kids/">Kids</option>
    <option value="size-guide-adults/">Adults</option>
</select>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage'
    ], function($){
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myURLs").change(function() {
                var popUrl = this.value;
                console.log(popUrl);
                if(popUrl!=""){
                    winpops=window.open(popUrl,"","width=1000,height=700,resizable,");
                    console.log(winpops);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```